# Inconsistent results with booleanfunction and booleantable

Tags: boolean-computation

Can someone please explain the inconsistent results I'm getting from BooleanTable and BooleanFunction?

Using the following truth table:

```
tt = {{1, 1, 1, 1} -> 1, {1, 1, 1, 0} -> 1, {1, 1, 0, 1} -> 1,
      {1, 1, 0, 0} -> 0, {1, 0, 1, 1} -> 1, {1, 0, 1, 0} -> 1,
      {1, 0, 0, 1} -> 0, {1, 0, 0, 0} -> 0, {0, 1, 1, 1} -> 1,
      {0, 1, 1, 0} -> 0, {0, 1, 0, 1} -> 0, {0, 1, 0, 0} -> 0,
      {0, 0, 1, 1} -> 0, {0, 0, 1, 0} -> 0, {0, 0, 0, 1} -> 0,
      {0, 0, 0, 0} -> 0};
```

I can produce the following boolean expression:

```
bb = BooleanFunction[tt, {a1, a0, b1, b0}]
(* (a0 && a1 && b0) || (a0 && b0 && b1) || (a1 && b1) *)
```

However, if I compute the truth values from this expression, I get different values from the original truth table:

```
tt1 = Boole[BooleanTable[bb]]
(* {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

If I turn this into a truth table and compute its boolean expression, I get a different boolean expression from the first one computed:

```
tt1Full = MapThread[Rule,
  {Keys[BooleanTable[Boole[{a1, a0, b1, b0}] -> 0, {a1, a0, b1, b0}]], tt1}
 ]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1} -> 1, {1, 1, 1, 0} -> 1, {1, 1, 0, 1} -> 1,
    {1, 1, 0, 0} -> 0, {1, 0, 1, 1} -> 1, {1, 0, 1, 0} -> 0,
    {1, 0, 0, 1} -> 0, {1, 0, 0, 0} -> 0, {0, 1, 1, 1} -> 1,
    {0, 1, 1, 0} -> 0, {0, 1, 0, 1} -> 1, {0, 1, 0, 0} -> 0,
    {0, 0, 1, 1} -> 0, {0, 0, 1, 0} -> 0, {0, 0, 0, 1} -> 0,
    {0, 0, 0, 0} -> 0} *)

bb1 = BooleanFunction[tt1Full, {a1, a0, b1, b0}]
(* (a0 && a1 && b1) || (a0 && b0) || (a1 && b0 && b1) *)
```

However, if I repeat this process, I end up with the original truth table and boolean expression it produces:

```
tt2 = Boole[BooleanTable[bb1]]
(* {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)

tt2Full = MapThread[Rule,
  {Keys[BooleanTable[Boole[{a1, a0, b1, b0}] -> 0, {a1, a0, b1, b0}]], tt2}
 ]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 1} -> 1, {1, 1, 1, 0} -> 1, {1, 1, 0, 1} -> 1,
    {1, 1, 0, 0} -> 0, {1, 0, 1, 1} -> 1, {1, 0, 1, 0} -> 1,
    {1, 0, 0, 1} -> 0, {1, 0, 0, 0} -> 0, {0, 1, 1, 1} -> 1,
    {0, 1, 1, 0} -> 0, {0, 1, 0, 1} -> 0, {0, 1, 0, 0} -> 0,
    {0, 0, 1, 1} -> 0, {0, 0, 1, 0} -> 0, {0, 0, 0, 1} -> 0,
    {0, 0, 0, 0} -> 0} *)

bb2 = BooleanFunction[tt2Full, {a1, a0, b1, b0}]
(* (a0 && a1 && b0) || (a0 && b0 && b1) || (a1 && b1) *)
```

Comment: My guess is that it is some behind-the-scenes sorting somewhere. Note that your original `bb = BooleanFunction[tt, {a1, a0, b1, b0}]` evaluates to a different function than if you switch the order of the symbols: `bb = BooleanFunction[tt, {a1, b1, a0, b0}]`. Then `Boole[BooleanTable[bb]]` is different in the two cases.

Comment: Indeed. If you use `{a0, a1, b0, b1}` (the canonical *Mathematica* ordering of those symbols) throughout, everything is consistent.

Comment: Further evidence that it is a sorting issue. When you evaluate `Cases[BooleanTable[bb] // Trace, {a0, a1, b0, b1}, Infinity]` with your original `bb`, you find many instances of `{a0, a1, b0, b1}`, but if you evaluate `Cases[BooleanTable[bb] // Trace, {a1, a0, b1, b0}, Infinity]`, you get nothing back. The point, I think, is that `BooleanTable` *cannot know the original ordering of the symbols*, and so it uses the canonical ordering, which messes things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is sorting of the list `{a1, a0, b1, b0}` that is going on under the hood in the evaluation of `BooleanTable`. For evidence of this, if we "spelunk" the evaluation of `BooleanTable` using your original `tt` and `bb`, the following occurs:

```
tt = ... (*as defined in the OP*);
bb = BooleanFunction[tt, {a1, a0, b1, b0}]
(* (a0 && a1 && b1) || (a0 && b0) || (a1 && b0 && b1) *)
```

Then,

```
Through[{Length, Union}@Cases[BooleanTable[bb] // Trace, {a0, a1, b0, b1}, Infinity]]
(* {13, {{a0, a1, b0, b1}}} *)
```

and

```
Cases[BooleanTable[bb] // Trace, {a1, a0, b1, b0}, Infinity]
(* {} *)
```

The point is that `BooleanTable` *cannot know the original ordering* `{a1, a0, b1, b0}` *of the list*, because you have not specified it, and so it *must* use the canonical ordering `{a0, a1, b0, b1}`. This introduces sorting errors relative to your original list of symbols, and thus the following results aren't consistent.

My best guess for why doing it *twice* recovered the original list is because `{a1, a0, b1, b0}` and `{a0, a1, b0, b1}` are related by an order-2 permutation, and so doing the same thing twice "undid" the original sorting.

Finally, the solution.

- Always use a list of symbols in canonical ordering, by using for instance `Sort@{a1, a0, b1, b0}` or an automatically sorted list like `Array[a, 4]`, or
- Use the second argument of `BooleanTable` that specifies the symbols, and keep the same ordering throughout, e.g.

  ```
  bb = BooleanFunction[tt, {a1, a0, b1, b0}];
  BooleanTable[bb, {a1, a0, b1, b0}];
  ```

  This fixes the inconsistency. Notice that

  ```
  lst = {a0, a1, b0, b1};
  BooleanTable[BooleanFunction[tt, Sort@lst]] === BooleanTable[BooleanFunction[tt, lst], lst]
  (* True *)
  ```

  For a pretty simple example of this, evaluate the following and note that the results are *different*:

  ```
  BooleanTable[a || (b && c), {a, b, c}]
  BooleanTable[a || (b && c), {b, c, a}]
  ```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this, particularly the reason why providing a variable list in BooleanTable makes such a difference.

Comment: @BCott. I recommend taking my answer with a slight grain of salt. This is the very first time I have looked into these functions, so I could easily have missed something. Nonetheless, I'm pretty sure that this is the issue.